# Sencha Android Native App

Tags: android, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, packaging

I'm trying to package my Sencha app into a .apk file.
Here's how the config file looks :

```
{
    "applicationName":"NotesApp",
    "applicationId":"NotesApp",
    "iconName":"icon.png",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "outputPath":"~/wamp/www/NotesAppPackage",
    "webAppPath":"~/wamp/www/NotesApp",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"~/Users/Vishrut/Desktop/my-release-key.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"alias_name",
    "sdkPath":"~/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk-windows",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
[INFO] ""~/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk-windows/tools/android" create
 project --target android-7 --name NotesApp --activity STActivity --path "C:\wam
p\www\NotesApp\build\native/" --package NotesApp"
Failed to create android project
Failed to package application
[ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I've checked the paths, they seem alright. ApplicationID can be anything, right? Could there be a problem in the way the path is specified (i.e spaces not allowed etc)?

I'm installing android api 7, and then trying it again.

Comment: Try setting your paths relative from your packager.json file... also in your app.json at the bottom there is a debug config with a value of "no" this needs to be set to "false"

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any API level. Specify a API level eg: 16...If you are using API level 16 then you must download the corresponding OS Image in this case 4.1 (Jelly Bean).

List of API levels and corresponding OS versions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Also specify the certificatePassword which you used in making the keystore. Then try again if you have more problems repost. Packaging for Android the first time was not easy for me either...